# MockMVC returned empty body

Tags: java, junit, mockmvc

When I mock passing valid id, the test run successful, but when I pass invalid id, the returns return 404, which was expected, but there are no response, and when I normal Http Request, it returns response body with message not found and status 404. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserControllerTest
{
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;


    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private User user;


    @Before
    public void setUp() 
    {

        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
        jacksonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jacksonMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.valueOf("application/json")));
        jacksonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);


        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(userController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandlerAdvice())
                .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
                .build();
        user = createTestUserEntity();
    }

    private User createTestUserEntity()
    {
                // create and return user block
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetReturnSuccessWhenParamIsValid() throws Exception
    {
                 // this code here returns normally json body with user object in it
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetReturnErrorWhenUserIdLessThan0() throws Exception
    {
               given(userService.getUser(anyObject())).willReturn(user);
           this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/-1")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value(404))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("not found"))
            .andReturn();
    }
```

In the method testGetReturnErrorWhenUserIdLessThan0(), there should be response body with status 404 and message not found, but when I test, it returns empty.

Here's the result logs:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /user/-1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.status": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$3.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:164)
    at com.examaple.test.api.controllers.UserControllerTest.testGetReturnErrorWhenUserIdLessThan0(UserControllerTest.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

The response should be like this:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "not found"
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/{userId:\\d+}")
    public ResourceResponse<UserView> getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String _id)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException
    {
        UserId userId;
        try {
            userId = UserId.of(_id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException _e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("not found");
        }
        User user = userService.getUser(userId);
        return new ResourceResponse<>(new UserView(user));
    }
}
```

UserId Class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class UserId
{

    @NonNull
    private Long userId;

    public static UserId of(@NonNull String _userId)
    {
        return User.of(Long.parseLong(_userId));
    }

    public static UserId of(@NonNull  Long _userId)
    {
        if (_userId <= 0L) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Param 'userId' is not valid; Got %s", _userId));
        }
        return new UserId(_userId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return userId.toString();
    }

    public Long toLong()
    {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your controller code look like?

Comment: Please add the controller code to your post.

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ I add controller class

Comment: What does UserId.of do? Because it seems you want to test that it throws an IllegalArgumentException, but my best guess is the UserId.of doesn't throw a IllegalArgumentException and just goes on with the code. Or are you expecting userService.getUser to throw a similar exception with the message not found?

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ I added UserId class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request `/user/-1` doesn't match the handler mapping `@GetMapping("/{userId:\\d+}")` you think it does.

`\d` is:

> A digit: [0-9]

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Yeah, I know. That’s what I’m trying to produce. An error, not a valid one. there should be error or not found response from that request, not empty. Do you know idea why?

Comment: I’m pretty sure I misconfigure something in the unit test configuration but I don’t what

Comment: Why do you think "there should be error or not found response from that request, not empty" when your handler method is not even being called? Are you trying to write a test for the default error handling? Are you using Spring Boot? The default error handling in Spring Boot is the job of the `BasicErrorController`. You don't need to write a unit test for that - you can trust that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The ID you receive in your controller method is a String, so Java will use the String method in the UserId class. As you can see, the implementation of that method will never produce a IllegalArgumentException and that is why your test is failing.

There is a lot to say about here of the code quality, but I think it is most important you understand why this code will never produce the expected test result in this case.